# Wrong Route called if string parameter is empty. Looking for Rest API standard to avoid this

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Controller Level

```
[Route("employee/members")]
```

Method Route 1)

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("memberSearch/{searchValue}")]
```

Method Route 2)

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{memberID}")]
```

Scenario 1:
http://localhost/api/applications/employee/members/memberSearch/Jacob
This will route to route1

Scenario2:
http://localhost/api/applications/employee/members/memberSearch/
This will route to route2 with memberID= “memberSearch” which is wrong as search page will try to access completely method

i know i can add Route 2 as

```
[Route("memberID/{memberID}")]
```

but this is not good Rest API standard

Comment: Why would you call http://localhost/api/applications/employee/members/memberSearch without supplying `{searchValue}`?

Comment: lets go with assumption that user made a mistake. And you are right from UI layer i will check for empty string but for the sake of conversation and assume these APIs are exposed to 3rd party to make calls. And person that making call sending a empty string.

Comment: If callers don’t stick to the API contract then getting the “wrong” result is a perfectly reasonable response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your route like below to make `searchValue` optional:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("memberSearch/{searchValue?}")]
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to perform a search, I would usually use the base route http://localhost/api/applications/employee/members with an added query parameter of name
so you could do http://localhost/api/applications/employee/members?name=Jacob. Using Query parameters will allow you to be more flexible with your searches in the future, e.g. adding pagination would be like http://localhost/api/applications/employee/members?name=Jacob&page=2.

Using the above would allow your routes not to overlap and if you wanted to make the search route more unique just change the HttpGet attribute to `[HttpGet("search")]` resulting in http://localhost/api/applications/employee/members/search?name=Jacob

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("employee/members")]
public class YourControllername : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Search([FromQuery] string name) {
        // Provide Search Functionality Here
    }

   [HttpGet("{memberID}")]
   public IActionResult Get(string memberID){
       // More code here
   }
}
```